# use sql bulk copy for dependent table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have two `DataTable` , `tblSoftware` and `tblDeviceSoftware` design are as follows:

`tblSoftware`  ->  `SoftwareID|SoftwareName|Version`

`tblDeviceSoftware`  ->  `DeviceSoftwareID|DeviceID|SoftwareID|SoftwareName|Version`

i have 300-500 records and i want to use [SQL BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) for this scenario. If same `softwareName` exists then do not insert it. I am using WCF service to insert. I will get `DeviceID` in sql by `DeviceName`. What can be best suitable way to insert it in the database apart from row by row insertion.

Answer (score 0):

I've had quite a bit of success using the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class available in the .NET Framework.

However, with SQL Bulk Insert or SqlBulkCopy I don't believe that you can selectively determine which records are added to the destination table. Rather, everything in the source is added (or attempted depending upon key violations, etc).

What you could do is create a different destination table in SQL Server, bulk insert the data to this table, and then perform an insert query to insert only the necessary records into the destination table.

Otherwise, you'd need to perform your tests such that you change the source data to only include the records you need to add to the destination table. My hunch is that this approach would be slower than performing this test in SQL Server as part of the insert statement.